# Zend\db\sql - prepareStatementForSqlObject - still need to bind or worry about sql injection?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

I'm using zf 2.4 and for this example in Zend\db\sql. Do I need to worry about sql injection or do I still need to do quote() or escape anything if I already use prepareStatementForSqlObject()? The below example will do the blind variable already?

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('foo');
$select->where(array('id' => $id));

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Select` class will cleverly check your predicate(s) and add them in a safe manner to the query to prevent SQL-injection. I'd recommend you to take a look at the source for yourself so I'll point you to the process and the classes that are responsible for this in the latest ZF version.

**Predicate Processing**
Take a look at the class [PredicateSet](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/Sql/Predicate/PredicateSet.php). The method `\Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate::addPredicates` determines the best way to handle your predicate based on their type. In your case you are using an associative array. Every item in that array will be checked and processed based on type:

- If an abstraction replacement character (questionmark) is found, it will be turned into an `Expression`.
- If the value is `NULL`, an IS NULL check will be performed on the column found in the key: `WHERE key IS NULL`.
- If the value is an array, and IN check will be performed on the kolumn found in the key: `WHERE key IN (arrayVal1, arrayVal2, ...)`.
- Otherwise, the predicate will be a new `Operator` of the type 'equals': `WHERE key = value`.

In each case the final predicate to be added to the `Select` will be implementing `PredicateInterface`

**Preparing the statement**
The method `\Zend\Db\Sql\Sql::prepareStatementForSqlObject` instructs its adapter (i.e. PDO) to create a statement that will be prepared. From here it gets a little bit more complicated.

`\Zend\Db\Sql` is where the real magic happens where in method `\Zend\Db\Sql::createSqlFromSpecificationAndParameters` the function [vsprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) is used to build the query strings, as you can [see here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/Sql/AbstractSql.php#L217).

**Note**
Please consider using the new [docs.framework.zend.com](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-db/sql/) website from now on. This website is leading when it comes to documentation of the latest version.

Comment: As I mentioned I'm using 2.4 so that's why I use that doc instead. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Does this help you? Please consider accepting my answer if it answers your question.